# strptime() not parsing datetimestring

Tags: c

It appears to me that `strptime()` cannot parse a datetime string like `"20221116090350"`.

This code demonstrates the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct tm stm; time_t utm; char *p;   
  char strtime[]="20221116082310"; // yyyymmddhhmmss

  memset(&stm,0x0,sizeof(stm));
  p=strptime(strtime,"%Y %m %d %H %M %S",&stm);
  utm=mktime(&stm);
  printf("%lu %s\n",(unsigned long)utm,ctime(&utm));

  memset(&stm,0x0,sizeof(stm));
  p=strptime(strtime,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S",&stm);
  utm=mktime(&stm);
  printf("%lu %s\n",(unsigned long)utm,ctime(&utm));

  // expected Wed Nov 16 08:23:10 CET 2022 (in Italy)
  // but got Thu Jan  1 00:59:59 1970
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with: `gcc -Wall -g testStrptime.c`  on AIX 5.3

run with: `./a.out`

This is the full output:

```
4294967295 Thu Jan  1 00:59:59 1970
4294967295 Thu Jan  1 00:59:59 1970
```

Where I am wrong?

Is there a way to let `strptime()` to broke down a timestring like `"yyyymmddhhmmss"` ?

Comment: I tried it [on Ideone](https://ideone.com/c6sMvw), works just fine. And no, the spaces between conversion specifiers are *not* significant. What system are you on, perhaps it's not fully compliant?

Comment: You have *two* calls to `strptime`. Are both failing or only one? What is the actual output of your *whole* program? Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete output.

Comment: Both failing. Compiled and run on AIX 5.3, gcc version 2.9-aix51-020209

Comment: You are missing `#include <string.h>` and missing the `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` macro required by `strptime()`. See [man 3 strptime](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) and [man 3 memset](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html) (note: `#define _GNU_SOURCE` will include the needed defines as well) After correcting the issues `1668608590 Wed Nov 16 08:23:10 2022` for both. Also note `p` is set but unused and `argc` and `argv` are both unused indicating `int main (void)` would be the correct invocation for `main()` in your case. (add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yes, after adding `#include <string.h>` and `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` compiles and run well on Linux but this has no effect under AIX 5.3 . Yes, AIX 5.3 dates about 2008 and is somewhat old.

Comment: @ulix - Oh... Check the man pages on your AIX system then. They may have different macro requirements for `strptime` and there may have been slight changes between POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008. No AIX box handy to test on.

Comment: This problem is present in `5300-12-09-1341`, but fixed in `6100-09-01-1341` So I suggest upgrading.